# Why do Hindus shave a baby's head (first hair cut)?

Tags: tradition

Why is it that people shave babies' head, be it a boy or girl, when they go for the baby's first haircut? According to my sub religion i.e. Vaishnav (Gujarati), we call it as a Mundan *(Head shaving ceremony)*.

This is done after a specific period of time after the birth of the child, and as far as I know, most of the Hindu sub castes follow this pratha *(tradition/practice)*.

According to me, Hindus shave their head when some relative, or a close member of their family dies.

So what's the reason behind shaving the hair off for the first time after the birth of the baby?

Comment: As per my reading, it is a respect shown towards God by sacrificing their beauty (_it seems Hindus believe tonsure as ugliness_). and also when elders die they show respect and dignity towards the passed one.

Comment: According to me they shave head of newborn baby because past birth history is stored in the hair as it may affect life in this birth

Comment: Actually what I heard is lil bit of science... They say the dirt ll be accumulated in scalp while the baby is in uterus and during birth..this has to done by means of headshave as it cleans the scalp by removal of hairs and layer of dead cells

Comment: In Rajput families ears are also pierced at Time of Mundan ceromony. Also Janeoo( sacred thread is also worn by the kid. Is this true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the scripture, it is **done for the spiritual benefit** of the child **in the first or the third year** after his/her birth:

> **As per the direction of the revealed texts**, the *chuda karma*
>   (tonsure) must be performed, for the sake of spiritual merit (observing *dharma*), by all
>   twice-born men in their first or third year. [Manu - 2.35]

As per the *mantras* used while performing *chuda karma*, the benefits are longevity of life, freedom from diseases and attainment of strength, health, vigor and good progeny.

Comment: Is there any inner significance apart from believing it as a samskara ?

Answer (score 4):

It's part of [Saṃskāra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83sk%C4%81ra), which are said to be a purification process<sup>[1]</sup>. There are 16 Saṃskāra and  Chudakarana (Mundan/First Hair cutting) is one of them. Some believes says birth hairs are undesired traits from the past births and this ceremony is used to set the child free from past birth.

[1]: PV Kane, [Samskara, Chapter VI](https://archive.org/stream/historyofdharmas029210mbp#page/n317/mode/2up), History of Dharmasastras, Vol II, Part I, Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute, pages 260-265

Comment: Original source has been cited and post-notice has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

It is a part of shodasa samskaras prescribed by the scriptures as the users above explained very well. But I want to say a thing. The shave is called as *Kesha Khandanam*
 when  hair is offered to god as a sacrifice or in auspicious situations like first shave.

It is called as *shiromundanam* when hair is  removed during inauspicious situations (when someone passed away) and to insult anyone. There is also an example of shiromundanam in Mahabharata. Jayadhratha (sindhu naresh) tries to abduct draupadi in the absence of Pandavas. After sometime Bhima and Arjuna rescue Draupadi. Bhima punishes him by his mighty blows. . As a symbol of insult in their hands, Bhima shaves the hair of Jayadhratha with a crescent shaped arrow with five tufts at as many places and drives him to their hermitage in the chariot. Yudhishtira orders Bhima not to kill him and set him free. Yudhishtira tells Saindhava not to do such lustful things again. The Sindhu naresh bows to Yudhishtira and the sages and leaves the place sorrowfully.

Source- [Draupadi harana parva](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03270.htm) from Mahabharata.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 1):

Raja Janmeja invited 18 high ranking brahim priests to a Jaagu, for a blessing. Brahmins and Sadhu's of India carried their unshorn hair on their head as a top-knot.

Raja Janmeja and his Rani were serving the brahmins with food. For a reason related to the clothes of the Rani, the brahmins broke out in laughter. The Raja felt humiliated and got annoyed with the invited brahmins to a point that he wanted to assassinate all of the high ranking priests. The Raja's adviser told him that this act for blessing would turn into a sinful act.

The adviser told the Raja to spare the brahmins but to assassinate their unshorn hair instead. At conclusion of the Jaagu the brahmins hatched a plan to justify their shaven heads with a small tuft/bodi/ sikha of unshorn hair.

Upon their return they preached that at this great spiritual gathering it has been revealed to them that hair should be shaved as an act of purification. The tradition of shaving the head was instigated amongst the followers.

Comment: Please add some sources link to your answer.