# Why Mundan (Chudakarma) is done in first and third year of life in Hindusim?

Tags: rituals, practice, samskara

Why first hair removal for kids is done at age of 1st and 3rd year and some places they do in 2nd year?

Which one is more appropriate and why?

Comment: most people do on 1st year. it is to remove papa(sin) associated with hair that came from birth.

Answer (score 6):

First hair removal that is also known as Chudakarma is mostly performed either in first year or third year. But some scriptures allow to perform it in fifth year, seventh year or according to family customs. This Samskara is necessary for spiritual growth.

[Manu Smriti 2.35](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu02.htm)

> 35. According to the teaching of the revealed texts, the Kudakarman (tonsure) must be performed, for the sake of spiritual merit, by all twice-born men in the first or third year.

[Vishnu Smriti 27.12](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe07/sbe07029.htm)

> 12. The Kûdâkarana '(tonsure rite) should take place in the third year.

[Apastamba Grihya Sutra, PATALA 6, SECTION 16](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/sbe30109.htm)

> 3. In the third year after his birth the Kaula (or tonsure is performed) under (the Nakshatra of) the two Punarvasus.

[Sankhayana Grihya Sutra, KHANDA 28](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29030.htm)

> 1. After one year the Kûdâkarman (i.e. the tonsure of the child's head);
> 2. Or in the third year;
> 3. In the fifth for a Kshatriya;
> 4. In the seventh for a Vaisya.

[Paraskara Grihya Sutra, KÂNDA II, KANDIKÂ 1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe29/sbe29174.htm)

> 1. When (the son) is one year old, the Kûdâkarana (i.e. the tonsure of his head, should be performed),
> 2. Or before the lapse of the third (year).

[Hiranyakesin Grihya Sutra, PATALA 1, SECTION 6](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/sbe30078.htm)

> 1. In the third year (he performs) the Kûdâkarman (i.e. the tonsure of the child's head).

[Gobhila Grihya Sutra, KÂNDIKÂ 9](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe30/sbe30021.htm)

> 1. Now follows the tonsure of the child's head, in the third year.

**Yājñavalkya, 1.12**

> ‘Tonsure is to be performed according to family-custom.’

**Āśvalāyana-Gṛhyasūtrā, 1.17.1**

> ‘Tonsure in the third year; or in accordance with the custom of the family.’

Comment: Great answer on 'when;. Do the scriptures also mention the 'why'?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Thanks. 'Why' part is not explicitly mentioned but there is one thing to be noted in Manu Smriti 2.35 `the Kudakarman (tonsure) must be performed, for the sake of spiritual merit`

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal One reason for why is, past karma is stored in hair (or to be precise bad karma). But i don't know any scriptural reference and i asked a question [What scriptures other than Dharma Sindhu say sins are stored in hair?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18170/3500)