Hindu Morality vs Practicality
Newbie here. I don't know about any texts. I am just asking this question out of curiosity and the things I hear/see around me.
Many things that are either being told to me or I see people practice them seems that they were practical at older times, but now, they seems odd.
Here are few:
1. Prohibition of Cutting Nails or Hair After Sunset
This teaches discipline and careful management of time, emphasizing that certain activities should be done during the appropriate hours. What I think its practical importance at that time would be is: In ancient times, lighting was minimal, and cutting nails or hair in the dark could lead to accidents. But, in today's world, with electric lighting, this rule might feel unnecessary.
2. Walking Around a Tulsi Plant
This practice encourages a connection with nature and reverence for life. It reminds people of the importance of plants in sustaining life. What I think its practical importance (at that time) would be: Tulsi has medicinal properties, and keeping it in the home improves air quality and hygiene. But, in mordern world, where they are tall buildings and many people in cities live in flats, this seems quite impossible to practice.
3. Placing a Lemon and Chilies on Doorways
This practice aims to ward off negativity and symbolize vigilance against evil influences. And its practical importance (what I think at that time) would be the acidic and pungent properties of lemons and chilies acted as natural insecticides, helping to keep homes hygienic. However, after looking at mordern pest control methods, this practice seems unnecessary.
Disclaimer: I am NOT saying that they are wrong. I am just asking that these practices might be necessary in older times, but in today's world, do these hold that much importance? Would  we be still bounded to practice them?

The points 1 and 3 are not examples of Hindu morality but customs. Anybody who does not believe in them shouldn't practice such customs.
The case of Tulsi plant is different. Tulsi plant is a form of Devi Laksmi according to some Puranas.

At that time Bhagavan Hari told them one by one: - 'O Laksmi! Let you
be born in parts, without being born in any womb, in the world as the
daughter in the house of King Dharma-dhvaja. You will have to take the
form of a tree there, out of this evil turn of fate. There Sankhacuda,
the Indra of the Asuras, born of my parts will marry you. After that
you will come back here and be my wife as now. There is no doubt in
this. You will be named Tulasi, the purifier of the three worlds, in
Bharata.

Srimad Devi Bhagavatam IX.VI

Thank you for clearing my confusion.

There are always Dharmic reasons for such instructions which one needs to understand.
1. Prohibition on hair cut etc. after sunset
This is because acts like shaving, haircut, nail cut make the body impure and to regain purity one needs to take bath.
As shown in this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27722:


After having rubbed oil on the body, after encountering the smoke from
a funeral pyre, after sexual intercourse, and after being shaved, one
remains a chandala until he bathes

One remains a Chandala until he bathes -- means he remains impure until he bathes.Now,if one does haircut or nailcut after sunset then one needs to take bath after sunset but bathing after sunset does not make one pure. It obviously cleanses the body but religiously or ritually it does not purify.
This is shown in this answer:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31657:


Bathing in the daytime, while being purified by the rays of the sun,
is the approved form of bathing. Bathing at night is not approved
unless when the Rahu is visible in the heavens.
Bathing, making of gifts, austerities, and burnt-offerings, may be
made at night when an eclipse is seen. Night otherwise is impure ;
therefore night is to be shunned in performing rites.

So, generally speaking, bathing does not purify if done in night. Only in some special cases it is allowed to take after sunset.
Now, we can understand why haircut etc. should not be done at night because in that case the person needs to wait till next day sunrise to regain purity.
2. Walking Around a Tulsi Plant
This is called circumambulation  or in Sanskrit Pradakshina. Keeping deities towards our right if we go around in cycles it's called Pradakshina. It's a way of seeking blessings from deity and it is also one among many Upacharas offered to deities during Pujas.

मृदं गां दैवतं विप्रं घृतं मधु चतुष्पथम् । प्रदक्षिणानि कुर्वीत
प्रज्ञातांश्च वनस्पतीन् ॥ ३९ ॥
mṛdaṃ gāṃ daivataṃ vipraṃ ghṛtaṃ madhu catuṣpatham |
pradakṣiṇāni kurvīta prajñātāṃśca vanaspatīn || 39 ||
By a mound of clay, a cow, a deity, a Brāhmaṇa, clarified butter,
honey, a cross-way and the well-known trees—he shall pass in such a
manner as to leave them on his right.— Manu Smriti 4.(39)

Since, Tulasi is a deity in Hinduism Pradakshina is done of it too. If you go to temples you will find many devotees doing the same around the idols.
There are various rules concerning Pradkshina of various deities as shown in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15361
3. Placing a Lemon and Chilies on Doorways
This is done to protect the place/house/shop from evil eye.As far as I know, these tricks are mostly mentioned in Shabar Tantras and not in any mainstream scriptures.However they are widely practiced.
If something is difficult to practice in modern times does not mean that the practice is outdated.It only signifies that the modern lifestyle is more or less Adharmic in nature and that makes it difficult to practice or follow Dharmic practices mentioned in scriptures.

Thank you for your simple explanation.

No problem @VanshPatel
