# What does Sanatana Dharma say regarding shaving pubic and anus hair?

Tags: customs, body

Some religions encourage, both men and women, to shave off their pubic hair and anus hair.

What does Sanatana Dharma say to its followers about this?

Answer (score 9):

**There is no instruction that the hairs on those parts should be shaved off.**

In fact we have the following verse:

> Manu Smriti 4.144. Except when sick he must not touch the cavities (of
>   the body) without a reason, **and he must avoid (to touch) the hair on
>   the secret (parts)**

So, it is quite clear that there is no rule that the hairs on those parts should be removed.

But, where it is a question of performing penances (for atoning for some sins that one has committed), several scriptures recommend shaving off hairs from all over the body. Because according Hindu scriptures [sins are stored in the hairs](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18170/what-scriptures-other-than-dharma-sindhu-say-sins-are-stored-in-hair).

For example, we have:

> 13. If the foetus of a cow is destroyed, while it is in an amorphous state, a quarter penance is prescribed for the sin; when it has
>       attained some distinct form, then the penance should be two quarters ;
>       by destroying a foetus which has not yet developed its consciousness,
>       the sinner must perform three quarters.
> 14. **In a quarter penance, the rule is to shave the hair all over the limbs ; in two quarters, the beard likewise ; in three quarters, the
>       shaving is to be of all hair, except the coronal lock; but on killing
>       after birth, the shaving includes the coronal lock too.**
>
> **Parashara Smriti Chapter 9**

But, that's only while engaging in a Prayaschitta. In ordinary circumstances there are no specific instructions.

Comment: So, even shaving of beard isnt allowed?

Comment: Yes allowed .. where it says that it is not allowed? @Rudra

Comment: i just thought that as its mentioned for penances, it is not allowed in normal case. Thanks.

Comment: Okay Thanks .. you came after a long time it seems? @Rudra

Comment: i come here quite a few times, just that i comment only when i have still doubts left

Comment: Ok ... that's good to know @Rudra