# Shaving the head of a baby outside of India

Tags: rituals, customs, samskara

I am getting more calls as a barber about this service. What does it entail? When I do a head shave I usually do a pre shave, 2 hot towels, hot later and the shave. What is the technique for the baby head-shave? I also heard the barber goes to the house for the party.

Comment: This is a unique predicament :-) Hindu barbers are a special caste and are anointed with certain duties and I assume they also have their own ritualistic procedures for performing their duties. Apparently carpenters, goldsmiths, weavers do. No idea how it will work with you.  Oh and it is not a party. Foreign Hindus are losing it , it seems. Some are getting this done with a priest! A brahmin does not perform this head-shaving rite. But NRI "priests" are doing it. The purpose of it is lost without the proper rite. Sorry this is more a commentary on the state of affairs than guidance for you.

Comment: @moonstar2001 you are talking about the Chaula ceremony right? AFAIK we just have a ceremonial cut of a clump of hair. The shave usually doesn't happen during the ceremony and is optionally done later.

Comment: @user1952500 that is just another modern-day hack people adopted.

Comment: Related [Why do Hindus shave a baby's head (first hair cut)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/572/why-do-hindus-shave-a-babys-head-first-hair-cut)

Comment: Well the role of the barber is to shave the head after the initial cut by the priest so I don't think you would have too many responsibilities. You can check this link for some information - https://www.babycenter.in/a1015415/imundani-ceremony